# Why is jquery's parseXML function failing when the XML looks ok?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, debugging, parsing

I have a pretty simple bit of javascript that attempt to parse the xml I've extracted from the metadata in a jpeg:

```
var xmlDoc;
try {
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlString);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Here is the exception that gets thrown:

```
Invalid XML: <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 4.4.0">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:photoshop="http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/">
         <photoshop:Instructions>C1DDZVs9Sr+DG5R9eSc%9w</photoshop:Instructions>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:aux="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/aux/">
         <aux:SerialNumber>1</aux:SerialNumber>
         <aux:Lens>AF-S DX VR Zoom-Nikkor 18-200mm f/3.5-5.6G IF-ED [II]</aux:Lens>
         <aux:LensID>1</aux:LensID>
         <aux:ImageNumber>6651</aux:ImageNumber>
         <aux:FlashCompensation>0/1</aux:FlashCompensation>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that XML. In fact, if I cut and paste that xml in directly, no exception is thrown:

```
var xmlDoc;
try {
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML('<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 4.4.0">       <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">          <rdf:Description rdf:about=""                xmlns:photoshop="http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/">             <photoshop:Instructions>C1DDZVs9Sr+DG5R9eSc%9w</photoshop:Instructions>          </rdf:Description>          <rdf:Description rdf:about=""                xmlns:aux="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/aux/">             <aux:SerialNumber>1</aux:SerialNumber>             <aux:Lens>AF-S DX VR Zoom-Nikkor 18-200mm f/3.5-5.6G IF-ED [II]</aux:Lens>             <aux:LensID>1</aux:LensID>             <aux:ImageNumber>6651</aux:ImageNumber>             <aux:FlashCompensation>0/1</aux:FlashCompensation>          </rdf:Description>       </rdf:RDF>    </x:xmpmeta>' );
} catch(e) {
    console.log("error parsing xml: " + e);
}
```

I can only assume that there must be some kind of unprintable special character in there somewhere that is causing the trouble. How can I test that assumption and fix it, or perhaps something else is wrong?

Comment: Note that jQuery itself doesn't parse XML at all - the browser does.

Comment: @Pointy, good point. This was failing in Chrome. I tried in FireFox and it parses ok. Now what can I do?!! Arg!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the problem. As I suspected, there was some nasty unprintable character lurking at the end of the string.

I was able to remove it with this dirty bit of hacking:

```
xmlString = xmlString.substr(xmlString.indexOf("<"), xmlString.lastIndexOf(">") + 1);
```

If it's not obvious, it simply trims away anything from the start and end of the string that isn't the expected angle brackets of an xml document. The jQuery function "trim()" was not effective at removing the rogue character as that only does whitespace.

I don't know what the character was, and I'm not particularly happy with my solution, but I'm too busy to spend more time on it. Sigh.

Comment: Would that character be binary? Just because you don't see it doesn't mean it's not there but trimming it this way assured that you're not including it in the variable. Good one.

Comment: Indeed. My worry is that there shouldn't have been any data at all after the final ">". If there happened to be a random ">" on the end somewhere, my hack wouldn't quite work and I would get this problem again. But what are the odds right? ;)

Comment: how did you extract the metadata from jpg? I'm more shamelessly interested in that part :)

Comment: I extended some great work by Jacob Seidelin: http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/jquery-exif-data-plugin.html for use with my site: http://www.stolencamerafinder.com/

Comment: Got an not so clean ouptut from a JSP page which leads in a falling parseXML.

After using your peace of code everything is working now!

Answer (score 0):

By using this website http://www.xmlvalidation.com, I got the following error message, make sure you check the box "Validate against external XML schema "

```
An error has been found! 

1:  62  cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'x:xmpmeta'.

XML document: 
1   <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 4.4.0">
2      <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
3         <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
4               xmlns:photoshop="http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/">
5            <photoshop:Instructions>C1DDZVs9Sr+DG5R9eSc%9w</photoshop:Instructions>
6         </rdf:Description>
7         <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
8               xmlns:aux="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/aux/">
9            <aux:SerialNumber>1</aux:SerialNumber>
10           <aux:Lens>AF-S DX VR Zoom-Nikkor 18-200mm f/3.5-5.6G IF-ED [II]</aux:Lens>
11           <aux:LensID>1</aux:LensID>
12           <aux:ImageNumber>6651</aux:ImageNumber>
13           <aux:FlashCompensation>0/1</aux:FlashCompensation>
14        </rdf:Description>
15     </rdf:RDF>
16  </x:xmpmeta>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. No external schema is defined so I don't know what that site is validating against. I also have other examples that are not failing in parseXML in Chrome but cause the same error on that website.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe** your problem is:
you can't use XML functions (in JS) on file that have no XML header.
try to open the XML file/input in the browser (type the path in the address bar),
and see if it opened as xml file or like text file.

for emample, adding XML header with php:

```
header ("Content-Type: text/xml");
```

Comment: The xml input data was actually just a string I manually ripped out of a binary jpeg file in javascript. I solved my own problem in the end (see my answer), but thanks for the suggestion.